# What's the best design pattern for PHP when Class_a only occasionally needs Class_b information?

Tags: php, language-agnostic, design-patterns, oop

This project is in PHP, but is fairly language agnostic. I'm building a project that has the following MVC format

```
Main_Class
Main_Class_Common
  --> Class_A
  --> Class_B
  --> Class_C
  --> Class_...
  --> Class_K
```

Original requests go to the Main_Class which then includes the appropriate main sub class. The majority of a request will only need to access data in it's own class. However, there is a small bit of cross-class data. All sub classes need access to shared common functions in Main_Class_Common at all times.

For example,

```
Main_Class
Main_Class_Common
  --> Class_Projects
  --> Class_Clients
```

Usually, Class_Projects never needs data from Class_Clients except in one function it might need to call `$class_clients->get_client_details($client_id);` and the same occasionally happens in the reverse.

But both classes need to be able to call `$main_class_common->clean_input($myinput);`.

Currently, I'm using `Class class_a extends main_class_common()` for access to shared functions which works perfectly. But **is the best way to access Class_B from Class_A to just access the global $class_b variable occasionally or should I move the possible shared functions into the Main_Class_Common even though they are used only occasionally?**

The project right now is in the early stages of dev, so the current implementation can be changed easily.

Comment: What's the responsibility of `Class_Projects` and `Class_Clients`? Are these MVC controllers, DAL/repository classes or something else?

Comment: Currently, they are general classes holding all functions related to Projects or Clients, but their main function is as MVC Controllers. There is a totally separate DAL that they link into. The example function of `$class_clients->get_client_details` builds the query and gets the specific record from the DAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) would fit in here. Create a `Class_ProjectRepository` class and `Class_ClientRepository` class, that contain methods such as `get_client_details($client_id)`.

The MVC controller classes will make use of the repositories. For example, both `Class_Projects` and `Class_Clients` can use the `Class_ClientRepository` to retrieve client details.

The repository classes will build the query and call your DAL. Additionally, if you need actual domain objects such as `Class_Client` in your controller, you should also make the repositories responsible for transforming the DAL result sets into domain objects.